# Vitest doesn't seem to mock correctly

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vitest

I think I might be going a little nuts.

I have the following

`title.ts`

```js
import { useTitle } from '@vueuse/core';
import { t } from '@/helpers';

export const setTitle = (title: string): void => {
  console.log('in function', t); // -> consoles the actual function
  useTitle(t(title), {
    titleTemplate: `%s | ${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME}`,
  });
};
```

`title.spec.ts`

```js
import { describe, it, expect, vi, afterEach } from 'vitest';
import { useTitle } from '@vueuse/core';

import { setTitle } from './title';
import { t } from '@/helpers';

vi.mock('@vueuse/core', () => ({
  useTitle: vi.fn(),
}));
vi.mock('@/helpers', () => ({
  t: vi.fn(),
}));

describe('helpers: title', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('set title', () => {
    it('will set the title of the page', () => {
      t.mockImplementation(() => 'test');
      console.log('in test', t); // -> will console the spyed function
      setTitle('test');

      expect(t).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(useTitle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

I get the following error

> [intlify] Not found 'test' key in 'en' locale messages.
> AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once

I must not be understanding this correctly, but I thought that mocking the import path will cause the test to mock the import within the file that I am testing.

If I change both imports to `import * as helpers from '@/helpers` the tests run and pass, so I am very confused.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and after some research, I found this GitHub thread. Basically, this was a bug in vitest.

https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/4619

It is marked as closed, so it should fixed in a newer version of the package.